# Access google sheet using google API key credentials

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-oauth, httprequest, google-sheets-api

I was using google sheet from one application using htttp request like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXXXXXXX/exec`
but now Google has changed the access method. now I cannot access the URL mentioned above (XXXXXXXX : Replaced with my sheetid).
Now I was searching the access method and I found that we can also access using google API keys. which has to send in the HTTP request. Here is the page for more information.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps#httprest_1

But I am not getting a complete idea for HTTP request.
Anyone has tried the same or related.

Answer (score 1):

From the question

> I was using google sheet from one application using htttp request like https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXXXXXXX/exec but now Google has changed the access method. now I cannot access the URL mentioned above (XXXXXXXX : Replaced with my sheetid).

The `XXXXXXXX` is not the the sheetid, it's a unique id assigned to the corresponding web app deployment.

To get the web app full URL you have to go to your script, using the new Google Apps Script IDE, click on Deploy > Manage Deployments then select the corresponding deployment.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web